# jOOQ and StackOverflowException while fetching from a select

Tags: postgresql, stack-overflow, jooq

I use jOOQ 3.8.4 and Postgres 9.5.
I have a complex schema. Actually, when I do a simple select, like:

```
create.selectFrom(ARTICLE_VIEW)
            .orderBy(ARTICLE_VIEW.AV_CREATION_DATE
                    .desc()).limit(4).fetch();
```

I get:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.jooq.Converters$1.<init>(Converters.java:67)
    org.jooq.Converters.identity(Converters.java:67)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:2041)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:2130)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:2041)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:2130)
    org.jooq.impl.DefaultBinding.pgFromString(DefaultBinding.java:2041)
```

and more (funny, it is my first `StackOverflowException`)!

I activated the DEBUG logging mode, and I copied the select and execute it in PGAdmin. It works. There should be something wrong in jOOQ, but I do not know how to provide useful information. 
Posting the schema I use would be madness, it requires dozens of tables. Any hint on how to proceed?

---

UPDATE

Here follows the record class

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ
 */
package com.model.jooq.shop.tables.records;


import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

import com.model.jooq.shop.enums.BrandCountry;
import com.model.jooq.shop.enums.Color;
import com.model.jooq.shop.enums.Discount;
import com.model.jooq.shop.enums.Season;
import com.model.jooq.shop.tables.ArticleView;
import com.model.jooq.shop.udt.records.ArticleSimpleTypeRecord;
import com.model.jooq.shop.udt.records.CategoryTypeRecord;
import com.model.jooq.shop.udt.records.LocalizedMoneyRecord;
import com.model.jooq.shop.udt.records.SameModelArticleTypeRecord;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.jooq.impl.TableRecordImpl;


/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
@Entity
@Table(name = "article_view", schema = "shop")
public class ArticleViewRecord extends TableRecordImpl<ArticleViewRecord> implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1404712730;

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_id</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleId(Long value) {
        set(0, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_id</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_id", precision = 64)
    public Long getArticleId() {
        return (Long) get(0);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_model_id</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleModelId(Long value) {
        set(1, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_model_id</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_model_id", precision = 64)
    public Long getArticleModelId() {
        return (Long) get(1);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_name</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleName(String value) {
        set(2, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_name</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_name", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getArticleName() {
        return (String) get(2);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleNameForUrl(String value) {
        set(3, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_name_for_url", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getArticleNameForUrl() {
        return (String) get(3);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_season</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleSeason(Season value) {
        set(4, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_season</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_season")
    public Season getArticleSeason() {
        return (Season) get(4);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_year</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleYear(Short value) {
        set(5, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_year</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_year", precision = 16)
    public Short getArticleYear() {
        return (Short) get(5);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_standard_size_designation</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleStandardSizeDesignation(Boolean value) {
        set(6, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_standard_size_designation</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_standard_size_designation")
    public Boolean getArticleStandardSizeDesignation() {
        return (Boolean) get(6);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_ean13</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleEan13(String value) {
        set(7, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_ean13</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_ean13", length = 13)
    @Size(max = 13)
    public String getArticleEan13() {
        return (String) get(7);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_config_sku</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleConfigSku(String value) {
        set(8, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_config_sku</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_config_sku", length = 12)
    @Size(max = 12)
    public String getArticleConfigSku() {
        return (String) get(8);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_features</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleFeatures(JsonElement value) {
        set(9, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_features</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_features")
    public JsonElement getArticleFeatures() {
        return (JsonElement) get(9);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleColor(Color value) {
        set(10, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_color")
    public Color getArticleColor() {
        return (Color) get(10);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color2</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleColor2(Color value) {
        set(11, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color2</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_color2")
    public Color getArticleColor2() {
        return (Color) get(11);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color3</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleColor3(Color value) {
        set(12, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color3</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_color3")
    public Color getArticleColor3() {
        return (Color) get(12);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color_detail</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleColorDetail(JsonElement value) {
        set(13, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_color_detail</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_color_detail")
    public JsonElement getArticleColorDetail() {
        return (JsonElement) get(13);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_paid_price</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticlePaidPrice(LocalizedMoneyRecord[] value) {
        set(14, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_paid_price</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_paid_price")
    public LocalizedMoneyRecord[] getArticlePaidPrice() {
        return (LocalizedMoneyRecord[]) get(14);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_price</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticlePrice(LocalizedMoneyRecord[] value) {
        set(15, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_price</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_price")
    public LocalizedMoneyRecord[] getArticlePrice() {
        return (LocalizedMoneyRecord[]) get(15);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_image_filenames</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleImageFilenames(String[] value) {
        set(16, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_image_filenames</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_image_filenames")
    public String[] getArticleImageFilenames() {
        return (String[]) get(16);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_active_from</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleActiveFrom(Timestamp value) {
        set(17, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_active_from</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_active_from")
    public Timestamp getArticleActiveFrom() {
        return (Timestamp) get(17);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_discount</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setArticleDiscount(Discount value) {
        set(18, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_article_discount</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_article_discount")
    public Discount getArticleDiscount() {
        return (Discount) get(18);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_id</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandId(Short value) {
        set(19, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_id</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_id", precision = 16)
    public Short getBrandId() {
        return (Short) get(19);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_name</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandName(String value) {
        set(20, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_name</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_name", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getBrandName() {
        return (String) get(20);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandNameForUrl(String value) {
        set(21, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_name_for_url", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getBrandNameForUrl() {
        return (String) get(21);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_country</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandCountry(BrandCountry value) {
        set(22, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_country</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_country")
    public BrandCountry getBrandCountry() {
        return (BrandCountry) get(22);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_logo_url</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandLogoUrl(String value) {
        set(23, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_logo_url</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_logo_url", length = 250)
    @Size(max = 250)
    public String getBrandLogoUrl() {
        return (String) get(23);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_facts</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setBrandFacts(JsonElement value) {
        set(24, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_brand_facts</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_brand_facts")
    public JsonElement getBrandFacts() {
        return (JsonElement) get(24);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_id</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setCommodityGroupId(Long value) {
        set(25, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_id</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_commodity_group_id", precision = 64)
    public Long getCommodityGroupId() {
        return (Long) get(25);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_name</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setCommodityGroupName(String value) {
        set(26, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_name</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_commodity_group_name", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getCommodityGroupName() {
        return (String) get(26);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setCommodityGroupNameForUrl(String value) {
        set(27, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_commodity_group_name_for_url</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_commodity_group_name_for_url", length = 25)
    @Size(max = 25)
    public String getCommodityGroupNameForUrl() {
        return (String) get(27);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_categories</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setCategories(CategoryTypeRecord[] value) {
        set(28, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_categories</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_categories")
    public CategoryTypeRecord[] getCategories() {
        return (CategoryTypeRecord[]) get(28);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_sizes</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setSizes(ArticleSimpleTypeRecord[] value) {
        set(29, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_sizes</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_sizes")
    public ArticleSimpleTypeRecord[] getSizes() {
        return (ArticleSimpleTypeRecord[]) get(29);
    }

    /**
     * Setter for <code>shop.article_view.av_all_model_colors</code>.
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord setAllModelColors(SameModelArticleTypeRecord[] value) {
        set(30, value);
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for <code>shop.article_view.av_all_model_colors</code>.
     */
    @Column(name = "av_all_model_colors")
    public SameModelArticleTypeRecord[] getAllModelColors() {
        return (SameModelArticleTypeRecord[]) get(30);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructors
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Create a detached ArticleViewRecord
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord() {
        super(ArticleView.ACTIVE_ARTICLE_VIEW);
    }

    /**
     * Create a detached, initialised ArticleViewRecord
     */
    public ArticleViewRecord(Long article_id, Long article_model_id, String article_name, String article_name_for_url, Season article_season, Short article_year, Boolean article_standard_size_designation, String article_ean13, String article_config_sku, JsonElement article_features, Color article_color, Color article_color2, Color article_color3, JsonElement article_color_detail, LocalizedMoneyRecord[] article_paid_price, LocalizedMoneyRecord[] article_price, String[] article_image_filenames, Timestamp article_active_from, Discount article_discount, Short brand_id, String brand_name, String brand_name_for_url, BrandCountry brand_country, String brand_logo_url, JsonElement brand_facts, Long commodity_group_id, String commodity_group_name, String commodity_group_name_for_url, CategoryTypeRecord[] categories, ArticleSimpleTypeRecord[] sizes, SameModelArticleTypeRecord[] all_model_colors) {
        super(ArticleView.ACTIVE_ARTICLE_VIEW);

        set(0, article_id);
        set(1, article_model_id);
        set(2, article_name);
        set(3, article_name_for_url);
        set(4, article_season);
        set(5, article_year);
        set(6, article_standard_size_designation);
        set(7, article_ean13);
        set(8, article_config_sku);
        set(9, article_features);
        set(10, article_color);
        set(11, article_color2);
        set(12, article_color3);
        set(13, article_color_detail);
        set(14, article_paid_price);
        set(15, article_price);
        set(16, article_image_filenames);
        set(17, article_active_from);
        set(18, article_discount);
        set(19, brand_id);
        set(20, brand_name);
        set(21, brand_name_for_url);
        set(22, brand_country);
        set(23, brand_logo_url);
        set(24, brand_facts);
        set(25, commodity_group_id);
        set(26, commodity_group_name);
        set(27, commodity_group_name_for_url);
        set(28, categories);
        set(29, sizes);
        set(30, all_model_colors);
    }
}
```

---

**Possible source of the issue**

I debugged following the link from [Andrew Rueckert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425722), but it seems to be that the issue is in jOOQ. It does not handle properly types inside types.

The view contains a `ArticleSimpleTypeRecord` that is a PostgreSQL type. It has a type internally.
The steps executed in class `DefaultBinding` are:

1. method `pgFromString` is called with the default converter for the `ArticleSimpleTypeRecord`. This imply that the following instruction is called:

   else if (Record.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
       return (T) pgNewRecord(type, null, string);
   }
2. method `pgNewRecord` tries to create a record from the given object by calling the following method:

   ```
   public Record operate(Record record) {
           List<String> values = PostgresUtils.toPGObject(object.toString());

           Row row = record.fieldsRow();
           for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
               pgSetValue(record, row.field(i), values.get(i));
           }
           return record;
   }
   ```

   which will set the values into the record using the method `pgSetValue` and the values from the `object`.
3. When it comes to set the value for the `json` value jOOQ calls the method `pgSetValue(Record record, Field<T> field, String value)` which calls the method `pgFromString` using the converter for the field (i.e. [the `PostgresJSONGsonBinding` JSON converter I found on jOOQ website](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/)). The problem comes inside method `pgFromString`.
4. Inside `pgFromString`, the line  `Class<T> type = converter.toType()` returns `com.google.gson.JsonElement`, which is not binded by any default value so it goes to line:

   ```
   else {
       Converter<Object, T> c = (Converter<Object, T>) converter;
       return c.from(pgFromString(c.fromType(), string));
   }
   ```

   Here comes the issue, because the json converter should convert the value into a json starting from the object returned by `pgFromString(c.fromType(), string)`, but since `c.fromType()` returns `Object` and there is no default binding for Object in jOOQ is goes again to the default case and again and again and we have the `StackOverflowException`.

I had a look at the changes in that class, and seems that the current master has fixed the issue. There is now:

```
    else if (type == Object.class) {
        return (T) string;
    }
```

Then, I have to wait for the next jOOQ minor release. I hope it comes soon.

Comment: How are you generating your Record classes? (Posting `ArticleViewRecord` might help here.) It looks like there is a type in `ARTICLE_VIEW` that it is trying to deserialze from a String into a non-standard type, and it's getting stuck in an infinite loop. https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/version-3.8.4/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/DefaultBinding.java#L2130

Comment: @AndrewRueckert record class has been posted. So, I also suspect the same. The view was fine and the select also. I know replaced some json to be PostgreSQL types and this should be the issue. I'm just wondering how to debug this. The stacktrace does not help.

Comment: I compiled version 3.9.0-SNAPSHOT **unfortunately it has another bug**: there is no StackOverflowException, but it sets all the values of the inner type to null even if they are not

Comment: I found the issue with the null values. Jooq 1.3.9-SNAPSHOT returns the Record very well, also including the records for the included types. The problem happens when I do `fetch().into(ArticleView.class)` where `ArticleView.class` is a pojo

Comment: To overcome this issue, you can use a custom [`RecordMapper`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-execution/fetching/recordmapper/), that maybe could be registered via [`RecordMapperProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.8/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/). It is extra work, but it should work pretty fine!

Comment: @JeanValjean I will do a try!

Comment: @JeanValjean it works pretty fine!

Answer (score -1):

Have you registered a custom binding for JsonElement? We use Gson types as well, and had to do the following:

pom.xml (abbreviated)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>

    <configuration>
        <generator>
            <database>
                <forcedTypes>
                    <forcedType>
                        <name>GsonJson</name>
                        <userType>com.google.gson.JsonElement</userType>
                        <binding>com.mycompany.dao.bindings.GsonJsonBinding</binding>
                        <types>json</types>
                    </forcedType>
                </forcedTypes>
            </database>
        </generator>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

GsonJsonBinding.java

```
public class GsonJsonBinding extends GenericStringlikeBinding<JsonElement> {
   public GsonJsonBinding() {
       super("json", new JsonConverter());
   }
}
```

JsonConverter.java

```
public class JsonConverter implements Converter<Object, JsonElement> {
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public JsonElement from(Object t) {
        return t == null ? null : gson.fromJson("" + t, JsonElement.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object to(JsonElement u) {
        return u == null || u == JsonNull.INSTANCE ? null : gson.toJson(u);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Object> fromType() {
        return Object.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<JsonElement> toType() {
        return JsonElement.class;
    }
}
```